# How to connect to XMPP server using node.js

Tags: node.js, websocket, xmpp

Do I need to create XMPP server for real-time chat, how to create WebSocket with XMPP server? (I use node.js for programming)

Comment: And you goint to implement whole XMPP protocol by yourself?

Comment: Not quite as much as needed. I'm currently working with WebRTC (rtc.io for node.js).

Comment: Maybe [this](https://medium.com/@connectycube/xmpp-real-time-chat-in-react-native-8d6d5d23dd47) article will help you. You can use a ready backend and a library for building apps with messaging functionality – chat, user authorization, file attachments, push notifications and many more.